# How to get the mouse event of a mousedown event when I pass a parameter

Tags: javascript

```
    let bob = 'hello';
    
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart(event))
    
    let dragStart = function (event) {
      console.log(event) // undefined
    }
```

Here is some code, the event is equal to undefined, but how can I have it equal to the mouse event (so that I can get the target of the click)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the calling of the function into an arrow function (or any sort of function really)

```js
let bob = 'hello';

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => dragStart(event, bob))

let dragStart = function (event, bob) {
  console.log(event, bob)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are not passing a **reference** to a function as you set it up, you are **invoking** your `dragStart()` function immediately and the return value from it (which is nothing/undefined) is what is actually being used for the callback function reference. So, when the event actually does occur, nothing happens.

There is also no real reason to pass the `bob` argument to the function as it is declared as a Global variable, so it's accessible from anywhere.

You can wrap your call to your function with an anonymous function that you pass to `.addEventListener()`:

```js
let bob = 'hello';

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){dragStart(event)})

let dragStart = function (event) {
  console.log(bob, "The " + event.type + " event was triggered.");
}
```

Or, if you will only ever need the `dragStart` function as a callback to this event, you can pass the entire function into `.addEventListener()` instead of wrapping the call for it in another function:

```js
let bob = 'hello';

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){
  console.log(bob, "The " + event.type + " event was triggered.");
});
```

And, if you want to make it even more concise, you can use "[arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)" syntax:

```js
let bob = 'hello';

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  console.log(bob, "The " + event.type + " event was triggered.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a method to your event listener. Do this instead:

```js
    let bob = 'hello';
    
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', event => dragStart(event))
    
    let dragStart = function (event) {
      console.log(event)
    }
```

Comment: This answer comes out as the very same thing as what the question had...

Comment: This actually passes an anonymous function. The question passes what the function returns. `dragStart(event)` vs `event => dragStart(event)`

Comment: I'm thinking the question is asking for how to pass in `bob` and got the `event` bit covered. No?

Comment: It's hard to say. He did mention his goal is to get the target of the click